# How to properly write a RewriteCond for https and subdomains

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Thus far I've gotten this far with my RewriteConditions but it's from hacking and slashing from internet examples. They seems to behave a little funny at times, like showing the directory in the url, so I assume I'm not doing it right.

The desired behaviour: I have multiple subdomains all pointing to the same root. Based on the subdomain value I want to redirect to a sub-folder in the root. I also want to force HTTPS. I have multiple subdomains, but I'll only show two for the sake of brevity. All the other conditions are virtually identical.

Here's my .htaccess code:`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} purchase.mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !purchase/
RewriteRule (.*) https://purchase.mydomain.com/purchase/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} booking.mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !booking/
RewriteRule (.*) https://booking.mydomain.com/booking/$1 [L]
```

`

Thank you,

Mike

Comment: This looks fine, do you have any problems?

Comment: Yes, the problem I seem to have is that at times the URL includes the subfolder in the path. I want the path to read just "https://purchase.mydomain.com" and not "https://purchase.mydomain.com/purchase/"

It seems inconsistent when this occurs though. I assumed it was the way my rewrites were written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(purchase|booking)\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =purchase.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^((?!purchase/).*)$ /purchase/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =booking.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^((?!booking/).*)$ /booking/$1 [L]
```

`http://` or `https://` in target will redirect instead of rewriting.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thank you. So will the above force HTTPS?